# During Jenkins build got this error : removeAttr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error during the jenkins build:

> TypeError: _myClassListID [i].removeAttr is not a function

```
var _myClassListID = jQuery(".myclass");
if (_myClassListID && _myClassListID.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < _myClassListID.length; i++) {
      myClassListID[i].removeAttr('role');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a jQuery object by index returns an Element object, not a jQuery object. To achieve what you need use `eq()` instead:

```
let _myClassListID = $(".myclass");
if (_myClassListID && _myClassListID.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < _myClassListID.length; i++) {
      myClassListID.eq(i).removeAttr('role');
   }
}
```

*However* it's worth noting that the null check, length check and loop are all redundant. jQuery will execute most methods on all elements in the collection for you by default, and will not error if the selector returns no matches.

As such the all the code in your example can be reduced to just this:

```
$(".myclass").removeAttr('role');
```